# How can i change Color of "Add Contact" button?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to change color of "Add Contact" button programmatically ?

Comment: Ah, you mean `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd]`.

Comment: if any of the answers worked you should mark them as correct or let us know did any of em work at all so we can try to help you

Answer (score 3):

Use property tintColor of UIButton:

```
UIButton* addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
addButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the button type is custom. Then doing the following will bring back those rounded corners:

```
[self.myButton.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[self.myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.myButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[self.myButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Though, personally, I'm a big fan of gradient buttons over solid colors... also, background color doesn't have different states, whereas background images do:

```
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Using an image, your button will darken with selection (or you could provide a different background image per state to do something different). This won't happen with background color, the background will always stay the same, only your button label changing per state.

Comment: It is tagged as iPhone so i'm assuming it is iOS, would be better if you used `UIButton` instead of `NSButton`